# ArgoCD - Dex SSO Configuration Issue: "User session error"

Tags: gitlab, single-sign-on, argocd

### Description

I am currently facing an issue while attempting to set up Single Sign-On (SSO) with GitLab on my ArgoCD deployment. I have deployed ArgoCD with HELM and I have configured Dex with the `values.yaml` file. I have set a sealed secret for the GitLab clientSecret. However, I am encountering a "The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed." on GitLab when trying to authenticate to ArgoCD with GitLab. When I trying to reach the dex server from UI (http://argocd-server/api/dex/callback) I faced `Bad Request User session error.`

### Details

#### Setup

- ArgoCD Helm Chart version: 5.47.0
- GitLab version: v16.3.4-ee

#### Problem Description

After configuring ArgoCD Dex server attempting to `Bad Request User session error.`.

#### Configuration Snippet

`argocd-chart/values.yaml`:

```yaml
argo-cd:
  server:
    config:
      url: 'http://ip:30080'
      dex.config: |
        connectors:
          - type: 'gitlab'
            id: 'gitlab'
            name: 'GitLab'
            config:
              baseURL: 'https://my.gitlab.com/'
              clientID: 'your-gitlab-client-id'
              clientSecret: $argocd-sso-gitlab:oidc.auth0.clientSecret
              redirectURI: 'http://ip:30080/api/dex/callback'
              groups:
                - Archi
              useLoginAsID: false
```

The `ip` is a `IngressController` Traefik exposed with a node port. Here is the ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: argocd-server
  namespace: argo-cd
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`argocd.example.com`)
      priority: 10
      services:
        - name: argo-cd-argocd-server
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`argocd.example.com`) && Headers(`Content-Type`, `application/grpc`)
      priority: 11
      services:
        - name: argo-cd-argocd-server
          port: 80
          scheme: h2c
    - kind: Rule
      match: ClientIP(`ip/32`)
      priority: 13
      services:
        - name: argo-cd-argocd-server
          port: 80
```

The two first rule are for access to ArgoCD app from my laptop (I add a line on /etc/host to resolve `argocd.example.com` as the node IP) and the third rule is for GitLab to be able to reach the ArgoCD app from the node IP.

#### Error Message

The Error Message from GitLab are:

[image: GitLab Error]

The Dex error are (http://argocd.example.com:30080/api/dex/callback):

[image]

#### Additional Context

- The GitLab clientSecret is stored as a sealed secret.
- Dex configurations are injected using ArgoCD Helm Chart values (As shown above)

### Request for Assistance

I am seeking guidance on resolving the "User session error" and ensuring the correct integration of Dex with GitLab for SSO. Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error that says "The request scope is invalid" generally means the token you generated doesn't have the appropriate scopes associated with it.

I'm using SaaS gitlab, but creating an application on my personal account w/ the 'read_user' and 'openid' scopes was enough to get SSO login working.

Just for reference, my config:

```yaml
data:
  url: https://argo.internal.somecompany.com
  dex.config: |
    connectors:
      - type: gitlab
        id: gitlab
        name: GitLab
        config:
          baseURL: https://gitlab.com
          clientID: <gitlab application ID>
          clientSecret: <gitlab application token>
          redirectURI: https://argo.internal.somecompany.com:5556/dex/callback
          scopes:
          - profile
          - email
          - groups
          groups:
          - mycompanygroup
```

The only issue I'm having otherwise is that the `useLoginAsID` value doesn't seem to make a difference for me, I'm having to specify the user's login email in Argo's RBAC CSV for applying groups to a specific user. I can apply a role to a group entirely, but also not a user in a group even with the email.

Eg:
`g, gitlabgroup, role:admin` - works
`g, mygitlablogin@domain.com, role:admin` - works
`g, gitlabgroup:mygitlablogin@domain.com, role:admin` - no works
`g, gitlabgroup:mygitlabusername, role:admin` - no works (regardless of `useLoginAsID` setting)
`g, mygitlabusername, role:admin` - no works (regardless of `useLoginAsID` setting)

Also, just for clarification, your Argo instance does not need to be exposed for GitLab to access; for example, I access Argo on an internal network through a VPN, so the ingress controller configuration is only needed if you need it yourself to access Argo.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! It permit to unblock me, you are right Argo do not need to be expose for GitLab so I remove my strange IngressRoot (I still used the one deployed by the chart Helm) and now I can add my app to Gitlab while trying to `LogIn via GitLab`. But I still have a problem, my app doesn't appear on GitLab UI while I have added it and I'm redirected to the login page a with a message `Login Failed.`, and url `/login?has_sso_error=true`, I don't know why, maybe still a problem with my dex conf ? or it is GitLab side ?

Comment: Not entirely sure, I haven't run into that error (even when using the same login process on my own app the last few days); perhaps try re-creating your app on gitlab and ensure your token/client ID are set correctly. Also ensure that your `redirectURI` is set correctly and matches the url you use/have configured for argo. The config I posted is what's working for me and I don't think the RBAC config or anything else might cause that issue but also ensure you have a `policy.csv` entry under `data` in your `argocd-rbac-cm` config map with your roles. I am/was using Argo 2.9.0. Good luck!